# Check table name to update data (sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two table like this

- table_CN (_id, name, phone, favorite, title)
- table_EN (_id, name, phone, favorite)

Then I select _id value from two table

```
SELECT _id, name, phone, favorite FROM table_CN where _id='15'UNION SELECT _id, name, phone, favorite FROM table_EN where _id='15'
```

After that I don't know how to determine which table name to update data, can I do that with SQL query?  I'm confusing here!

Comment: Are you trying to localize your tables or is the reason for those similar tables something else?

Comment: did not understand your query...do u want to update any one of the table after getting your select query output ?

Comment: the '_id' data in two table is unique value (never duplicate), so it only return just one value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the table name to the result manually:

```
SELECT _id, name, phone, favorite, 'table_CN' AS table_name FROM table_CN where _id='15' UNION
SELECT _id, name, phone, favorite, 'table_EN' AS table_name FROM table_EN where _id='15'
```

Btw, is there a reason to not use a table like `_id, lang, name, phone, favorite, title, PRIMARY KEY (_id, lang)`?